# Android studio properties window not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, properties

so i've learning a little about android studio recently, but every video i see, when they modify something from the "properties" window i have issues because mine says "atributes" and misses a lot of properties.

Does anyone know how to make it appear?
I have already tried a lot of stuff, like Window > restore default layout, also deleting the workspace, reinstalling android studio but i cant make it work.

I'll leave an imagen to show how i see it

https://gyazo.com/0cd32a07cefde36bb3fbbdaff5a9dff2

But every video i see has this

https://gyazo.com/300f41730bf495d8e0db05cb55d7f8d1

look at how many properties they have vs what i have, i already pressed the "view all atributtes" button

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the "attributes" table, you only need to check the "gear" icon on that window and select "All attributes table" instead of "XML attribute table".

[image: Icon]

For more details you can check 
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor

Comment: I just added another image to make it more clear, look the properties they have vs the attributes i have

Comment: Included image, clear on the gear icon and select the first option

Answer (score 2):

In Android studio 3.4.1 View -> Enter presentation mode then "attributes windows shows"

Answer (score 0):

I went into activity_main.xml, manually changed the text size of a button:

```
    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player 1: 0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Then I changed it back to the original size. Attributes window magically appeared again. Before I tried that, nothing else worked